# How to enable multiple minor modes in one shot?

Tags: minor-mode

In order to perform some debugging, I'd like to enable multiple (say `n`) modes: `mode-1`, `mode-2`, ..., `mode-n`. This can be done thanks to a `C-x C-e` at the end of each of the following lines:

```
(mode-1 t)
(mode-2 t)
...
(mode-n t)
```

but this is a pain if `n` is large (more than 50).  Is it possible to achieve the same result in one shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`progn`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/progn.html) to wrap an elisp body (multiple statements):

```
(progn
  (mode-1 t)
  (mode-2 t)
  ;; ...
  (mode-n t)
)
```

Evaluate using `C-x C-e` on last parentheses.